# Wordpress plugin: Update failed: Could not create directory. /var/www/html/wp-content/

Tags: wordpress, chmod

I am trying to update a WordPress plugin and I receive this error message:

`Update failed: Could not create directory. /var/www/html/wp-content/upgrade/akismet.5.3`

When I go to Tools > Site Health > Info > File Permissions, I see this:

[image]

How can I make those directories Writable? I thought it would by using 755 recursively for `/var/www/html/wp-content`, but I already have those permissions and it is still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the user Apache was running as. To fix it, I opened this file:

`/etc/apache2/envvars`, and I commented out a couple of lines, replacing them with the user that I wanted to run Apache as:

```
# Since there is no sane way to get the parsed apache2 config in scripts, some
# settings are defined via environment variables and then used in apache2ctl,
# /etc/init.d/apache2, /etc/logrotate.d/apache2, etc.
#export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_USER=jmontoya
#export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=jmontoya
```

Then I restarted Apache with `sudo service apache2 restart`.

I confirmed that Apache was now running as my desired user:

```
ps axo user,group,comm | egrep '(apache|httpd)'
root     root     apache2
jmontoya jmontoya apache2
jmontoya jmontoya apache2
jmontoya jmontoya apache2
jmontoya jmontoya apache2
jmontoya jmontoya apache2
jmontoya jmontoya apache2
```

Everything in `/var/www/html/wp-content` also belongs to `jmontoya`, which I specified it with `chown`. Permissions are properly defined with `chmod`.

Now I see what I expected:

[image]